# Preloading records that join on multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an app that helps tennis players find opponents. I have the following models:

`TennisMatch (id, description, user_id)`

`User (id, name, type)`

`AvailabilityWindow(tennis_match_id, start_time, end_time, requester_id)`

A user is able to use the app to post a tennis match listing. As part of that, they have to offer some availability. For example, if they wanted to play between 8-10am on Saturday. This would create an availability record as part of creating the match:

`AvailabilityWindow.new(tennis_match_id: 1, start_time: '8am Saturday', end_time: '10am Saturday', requester_id: user.id)`

If other players see the listing they can accept and agree to play at the proposed time and date. They can also suggest other availability, which would result in a record being added to the AvailabilityWindow table. So a tennis match can have multiple availability_window records from multiple different users.

My problem is this: I need a page that lists out all the tennis matches along with the availability that was suggested by the user who created the listing (ignoring any availability suggested by other users). For example

```
class TennisMatch < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :availability_windows
end
```

```
class TennisMatchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tennis_matches = TennisMatch.all
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @tennis_matches.each do |match| %>
  <h4><%= match.description %>
  <% match.availability_windows.where(requester_id: match.user_id).each do |window| %>
    <p><%= window.start_time %>-<%= window.end_time %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This does work, but suffers from a n+1, as it makes a query for each match to get the availability. How can I preload this data to avoid an n+1?

Let's also pretend that simply preloading all the windows e.g. `TennisMatch.all.includes(:availability_windows)` in the controller, and performing a `select(&block)` on the collection in the view to avoid a query is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class TennisMatchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    matches = TennisMatch.all
    user_ids = matches.pluck(:user_id)
    @tennis_matches = matches.includes(:availability_windows).
                        where(availability_windows: { user_id: user_ids })
  end
end
```

And then in the index.html.erb:

```
<% @tennis_matches.each do |match| %>
  <h4><%= match.description %>
  <% match.availability_windows.each do |window| %>
    <p><%= window.start_time %>-<%= window.end_time %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```